# OCR using a Neural Network

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, ocr, encog

I'm working my way toward understanding the usage of a NN in order to perform OCR, my goal is a bit different than the usual OCR algorithms.

My objective is to be able to determine if a specific input is a specific letter, for example I'm expecting to get the letter 'A' from the user, and I need to make sure I didn't get a different shape.

I need to be able to decide if a given input is the proper shape or not.

From what I've been reading, the are a few options here, MLP, SOM network, a back propagation network.

From what I understand, since I'm planning to create samples for each shape (letter) in order to train the network I should define a SOM network, is that correct?

I'm not sure which direction is preferred, if you could point me in the right direction that would be great.

I'm planning to use the Encog framework, not sure if that matters.

Comment: try caffe https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/tree/master/examples/mnist

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what you have described, SOM is not the best choice since it is an unsupervised classifier. You are specifying the class (letter) for each training example; therefore, a supervised classifier such as a multi-layer perceptron (MLP) is more appropriate.

With regard to MLP vs. back propagation network, that is a somewhat erroneous distinction. MLP is a type of artificial neural network (ANN), whereas back-propagation is a learning method. An MLP can be trained using back-propagation or via other methods (e.g., a genetic algorithm).

Comment: So if I understand you correctly, you suggest that for testing a given input for a match with a specific letter, I should create an MLP that has been trained on that specific letter and can decide if the input is correct?

Comment: It's not quite that simple and there are multiple ways you can set up your solution. One is to create an MLP with as many outputs as you have letters. Then, you would classify an input as the letter with the highest output value. Alternately, you could train a one-vs-rest MLP for each letter and use the appropriate MLP for a given test. Another factor is whether you will allow inputs that are not any of the trained letters but it isn't clear from your question if that is allowed.

Comment: Is one of the methods you mentioned more accurate than the other? I will not allow inputs that are not one of the trained letters.

Comment: Neither is inherently more accurate. Back-propagation is the most common method for training MLPs and is usually trained faster. If the input will always be one of the allowable letters, then a single MLP with as many outputs as letters is probably the way to go. Note that you will probably need one or two hidden layers in your MLP.